# Mandelbrot Set drawing and ZeroDivisionError in complex numbers

Tags: python

I am making a code that draws versions of the Mandelbrot Set. When it runs, it takes in two inputs, a and b, and converts it to a complex number (e.g. complex(a,b).) Then it draws a Mandelbrot set with z to the power of the complex number, plus c, unlike the normal version which is z**2+c. But some inputs for the complex number, like 5 and 6, sometimes give an error, ZeroDivisionError: complex division by zero, or sometimes, it gives no output whatsoever. Sometimes, when I put in 1 and 1, it works, and puts an output like this:

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so I'm not sure if that picture worked, but anyway, it looks nothing like the normal Mandelbrot set. What is happening? Also, this is my code:

```
import turtle
s=turtle.Screen()
t=turtle.Turtle()
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
h=complex(a,b)
t.pu()
t.goto(-200, 200)
turtle.tracer(0,0)
t.speed(0)
for y in range(200,-200,-1):
  turtle.update()
  for x in range(-250,200):
    t.goto(x,y)
    r=float(float(x)/170)
    i=float(float(y)/170)
    c=complex(float(r),float(i))
    z=complex(0,1)
    for exptest in range(50):
      z=(z**h)+c
      if abs(z)>2:
        if exptest>0:
          t.color('black')
          if exptest>1:
            t.color('yellow')
            if exptest>2:
              t.color('green')
              if exptest>3:
                t.color('red')
                if exptest>5: 
                  t.color('orange')
                  if exptest>10:
                    t.color('purple')
                    if exptest>20:
                      t.color('blue')
                      if exptest>30:
                        t.color('light blue')
        else:
          t.color('light green')
        t.dot(1)
        break
```

Comment: is "5 and 6" 5 + 6 i, or just the integer 5 or 6?

Comment: Could you add the full trace of the error, please?

Comment: Oh! I just realised a mistake, but it doesn't fix the ZeroDivisionError. I changed line 18 to be (0,0), instead of (0,1). At least now it produces something!

Comment: 5 and 6 is 5+6i.

Comment: And this is what it says in the terminal:

Comment: ZeroDivisionError: complex division by zero on line 20

Answer (score 2):

exponentiation is not well-defined for complex numbers. You can define `a ** b` ax `exp(log(a) * b)`, but `log(a)` is only defined up to `2pi i`, so you have an infinite number of possibilities. for *integer* powers, you can define `z**k` as `z * z * ... *z` `k` times, but this is almost certainly **not** what python does for `k` defined as `complex` as you do above.